# Kinematics question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration

An electric train accelerates uniformly from rest to a speed of 20m/s which it maintains until the brakes are applied. It is then brought to rest by a uniform retardation equal in magnitude to twice its former acceleration. The total distance covered is 7.8 km and time taken is is 7 minutes.

Calculate

- the time for which the train is travelling at constant speed,
- the initial acceleration in m/s^2.

Comment: Hi Taiyaba. Welcome to Physics.SE. This site deals with conceptual Physics Q&A. We don't encourage homework questions that doesn't involve any sort of work done by the *author* (which is you) and asks other users to solve the problem. If you think you could clarify your question, add *what you've done* along with your question. We're ready to help you. If you aren't clear, Please have a look at our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for more info. After improving the post, flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1):

Get a graphical approach to this kind of question.[image]

see this V-T graph of the scenario.

You can find everything. the slope gives acceleration.